# mongoDB atlas scaling with AWS regions

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, replication, sharding

I have 6 EC2 Instances on different region on AWS. I have only one MongoDB server on MongoDB Atlas (AWS). I am having latency issue while updating Data to the database. what is the best way to scale my MongoDB server with My 6 EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one way you can apply the VPC peering from EC2 to MongoDB Atlas (AWS). As MongoDB Atlas as now VPC peering function.

If you are trying to connect the MongoDB using public-facing network, then it might be slow.

AWS launched instances in a different region may create a connection using inter-region [cross VPC peering](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/).

So if you are following tradition way to whitelisting  ACL's better try this it will reduce latency issue.please peer all the region's VPC (make sure there will not be any IP conflict) and try to connect using private connections.

**EDIT : 1**

There is no additional penalty with MongoDB in terms of using it out of region, but most database protocols are not optimized for high latency conditions. You might be much better off setting up a read replica in other regions.

You can read this: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-fast-responsive-reads-cross-region-replication-mongodb-atlas

**EDIT : 2**

If you can't push your database to multiple regions (by using read replicas for example), then you should consider using CloudFront in front of your application(website) to allow for caching of requests in the different regions.

It won't technically improve the latency between application and database, but in terms of your user's perception of performance, it will be little speedy.

Comment: he just said they are on different regions (??), how can they be on the same VPC.

Comment: Does VPC make wires between regions shorter? I agree it is a must-have for security and billing purposes but how does it address the latency problem?